# How to alias Doxygen automated links to a different symbol

Tags: c++, c, documentation, doxygen

I use Doxygen *1.8.14* for my C API.

My API has some convention where an entity, let's say the `Flower` entity, is referenced to by an opaque pointer called `Flower` and a public structure called `FlowerData`.

Upon building Doxygen, it automatically generates hyperlinks for both `Flower` and `FlowerData`.

```
/// \brief Describes a pretty flower
typedef struct {
    Color color;  ///< Red? Blue? Unicorn?;
} FlowerData;

/// \brief Handle to a `Flower`
typedef void* Flower;
```

In this example, current documentation will generate two pages. `Flower.html` with the documentation to `Flower` and `FlowerData.html` with the documentation for `FlowerData`. **I want both documentation to have the same web page**, and any link generated from occurrences of one or the other symbol in the documentation to target it.

Is it easily achievable with Doxygen?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not easy achievable, but without a proper example and the doxygen version used it is even harder to tell.

Comment: There is not much to say about the code itself. Doxygen aside, it's just a struct and a void*. I use 1.8.14 and i've edited the queston. :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. With Doxygen 1.8.17, I get `doxtest_8c.html` and `struct_flower_data.html`. Links to `Flower` just stay on the `doxtest_8c.html` page, and links to `FlowerData` go to the other file. But it does work better if you replace `typedef void* Flower;` with `typedef FlowerData *Flower;`. You can then click through to the detailed page. I used the `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES` Doxygen configuration setting

Comment: Unfortunately in can't change the actual API, it's not work of mine. :) A solution I think of is: for I am not interested in the documentation of `Flower` anyways, just post-process Doxygen generation to replace all links from `Flower` to `FlowerData`'s doc.